# Get Client Machine ID

Tags: c#-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I need to get Client's Machine ID and their Country in my web application...

Is it possible get succeed in this?

Answer (score 0):

Host name:

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Resolve country:

```
public static RegionInfo ResolveCountry()
{
  CultureInfo culture = ResolveCulture();
  if (culture != null)
    return new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);

  return null;
}
```

from http://madskristensen.net/post/Get-language-and-country-from-a-browser-in-ASPNET.aspx

This uses the PC's setup Language/Country.

By IP try an example at:

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/06/finding-country-from-visitors-ip-in.html

Which involves checking the requesting IP adresses against a database of IP locations.

You could also use an IP for a service that already supports this such as:

http://www.ipgeo.com/api/

Comment: sorry :( it fails...i'm india but it shows US ....tell me frend, if you find gud ...

Comment: @Shankar yeah it uses the PC's Language/Country so if it's set to a different country then it fails. Your best bet is to do it via IP but there's a lot more work involved.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> using System.Globalization;
>
> string culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName;
> string country = culture.Substring(culture.IndexOf('(')
> ```
>
> + 1, culture.LastIndexOf(')') - culture.IndexOf('(')-

[Client Country in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/2e97d625-c7c9-4c6a-83a5-dc2b8ebd2dcf)

---

[Get Client Computer Name](http://forums.asp.net/t/821809.aspx/1?Get%20Client%20Computer%20Name),
[How to get the client machine name from a server](http://www.developerfusion.com/thread/30879/how-to-get-the-client-machine-name-from-a-server-m/)

> You will get most of the details of
>   the client machine using the
>   "Request.ServerVariables"
>
> ```
> // Try the following C# code 
> System.Net.IPHostEntry host = new System.Net.IPHostEntry(); 
> host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]);
>
> lbl.Text = host.HostName;
> ```

Comment: I really don't have any further opininon.Hope you can solve it. @Shankar